# SignalR message from client to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api running in azure and windows service locally running on premise. These 'client' logon on the Hub in the web api. When api sends out a command to all clients, all is well received. No problems here.
However, is it possible to send it signal from the same websocket from the client to the server, so from the windows service to the web api? Now my service calls a controller on the web api, but this feels redundant, cause there already would be a websocket available, right?

I am a bit new to signalR, so any help would be appreciate.

thnx!

Comment: did saw that post, probaly thinking it was the other way around, tahnk for pointing it out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `Invoke` method:

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:1235/");
var hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("myHub");

await hubConnection.Start();

hub.Invoke("MethodName", params...);
```

After creating the hub connection you can invoke a method call from the client with `Invoke` the first parameter is the methodname (of the method on the server you want to invoke) as string and with `params` you can send some parameter to the method.
If the invoked method has a return type it can be specified as generic `<>`:

```
var result = hub.Invoke<MyReturnType>("MethodName", params...);
```

Comment: any change on making it strongly-typed?

Comment: Not as far as I know.